Slow npm install on self-hosted GitHub runners in AWS Cloud (Windows)
We are experiencing slow execution times for the npm install command on our self-hosted GitHub runners in AWS Cloud. Here is our setup:
Infrastructure:
We use terraform-aws-github-runner module and Packer images.
Environment:

Windows Core 2022 image as base for our AMIs
PowerShell 7.1
Latest version of GitHub runner (v2.317.0)
Node.js version v20.14.0 and npm v10.7.0

Issue:
The npm install command runs extremely slow on our self-hosted GitHub runners. For instance, it takes around 5 minutes compared to 1 minute on GitHub-hosted runners. The process spends most of its time extracting packages from tgz files in npm cache.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

ReFS Partition: Attempted to run everything from a ReFS partition.
Different AWS volumes: Tried various types of volumes mounted from
AWS to the runner.
Manual Execution: Cloning the repository and running npm install
manually on the EC2 instance finishes in under a minute—showing it's
not a hardware or software issue but something related to the GitHub
runner integration.

Any advice?

Have you checked if the cache includes lots of old and unnecessary node modules in addition to the latest one? Some cache busting could help there. Also usually use of npm install is discouraged. Use npm ci instead. Did not get to browsing your repo for where the magic happens.

Yes. Ive cleaned the cache. Ive actually rebuilt AMI saved it and used only once for each experiment. To make sure there are no garbage in the pipeline.

What type of EC2 instance did you use? Both OS and instance type, as the latter can mean different bandwidth from your hosted runner. If you can provide the instance type of both, that could help us identify the issue.

Hi. its c7x something. It does not matter. As i said i can access the instance that ran slow npm install and run everything manually and it will work very fast. So i dont think machine is the issue here.

Did you execute the npm install directly in the  os of the runner or in another e2 machine?. Sometimes the virtualization fails and the only solution is delete and create a new one. Just to try, use Linux

After much debugging we established the cause of the problem. In the packer script, github runner is configured to run as scheduled task.
See script here.
If we run it as windows service under NETWORK_SERVICE credentials - it installs npm modules much faster. I will post fixed code as soon as we find suitable solution for this code.
